# Is NSTimer suitable for calling network every X minutes?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstimer

Is `NSTimer` the most appropriate method to schedule calling a network API every minute in an OS X application?

Will it affect system sleep, or use CPU cycles unnecessarily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSTimer is good for that. It won't poll and burn cycles and it won't affect sleep

Comment: If the user puts the system to sleep, does the timer just stop while it's asleep, then resume on wake?